# How to use cross apply to return 2 call records for each agent with least talking time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table stores record for each call including the ID of the call(`SessionID`), Talking Time and the ID of the agent who answered/missed the call(`ResourceID`). For each agent I want to return the shortest 2 call records. I have 39 agents receiving calls so i'm expecting to have 78 records in the output. I used the query below with cross apply but it is duplicating the 2 records for each agent 62 times(i'm using `where TalkTime > 0` to return answered calls only):

```
select ACD1.ResourceID,CONCAT(R.FirstName,' ',R.LastName) as [Agent Name], A.SessionID, A.TalkTime
from AgentConnectionDetail as ACD1
CROSS APPLY(select top(2) ACD2.ResourceID, ACD2.SessionID, ACD2.TalkTime 
            from AgentConnectionDetail as ACD2
            where TalkTime > 0
            and ACD1.ResourceID = ACD2.ResourceID
            order by ACD2.TalkTime,ACD2.SessionID ) as A
JOIN Resource as R
on ACD1.ResourceID = R.ResourceID
```

Actual output:

```
ResourceID  Agent Name  SessionID   TalkTime
1001    Liza Mccdonald  177235  31
1001    Liza Mccdonald  218346  70
1001    Liza Mccdonald  177235  31
1001    Liza Mccdonald  218346  70
.
.
1001    Liza Mccdonald  177235  31
1001    Liza Mccdonald  218346  70 >> record number = 124
1002    Ashly Peter 193873  57
1002    Ashly Peter 267030  44
1002    Ashly Peter 193873  57
1002    Ashly Peter 267030  44
.
.
1002    Ashly Peter 193873  57
1002    Ashly Peter 267030  44 >> record number = 257
.
.
1039    Scarlett Johnson    171696  24
1039    Scarlett Johnson    165479  70
1039    Scarlett Johnson    171696  24
1039    Scarlett Johnson    165479  70>> Last record in the output = 535362
```

Expected Output:

```
ResourceID  Agent Name  SessionID   TalkTime
1001    Liza Mccdonald  177235  31
1001    Liza Mccdonald  218346  70
1002    Ashly Peter 193873  57
1002    Ashly Peter 267030  44
.
.
.
1039    Scarlett Johnson    171696  24
1039    Scarlett Johnson    165479  70
```

Any idea what is wrong??

Comment: Please post the sample data and your expected output (in tabular form)

Comment: I did edit the post with the requested expected output, check it please.

Comment: using ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...) is workaround but i want to achieve this with CROSS APPLY. my query is working because it returns two records for each agent with shortest Talk time but i don't understand why it duplicate them many times!

Comment: It's basically because you've got `AgentConnectionDetail` in there twice. Not sure why everybody else is overcomplicating this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply directly on the Resource table.

Assuming that the ResourceID is the primary key in that table, thus unique.

```
SELECT 
  R.ResourceID
, CONCAT(R.FirstName,' ',R.LastName) AS [Agent Name]
, A.SessionID
, A.TalkTime
FROM Resource AS R
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP(2) ACD.ResourceID, ACD.SessionID, ACD.TalkTime 
  FROM AgentConnectionDetail AS ACD
  WHERE ACD.TalkTime > 0
    AND ACD.ResourceID = R.ResourceID
  ORDER BY ACD.TalkTime, ACD.SessionID
) A;
```

Another method is to use the `ROW_NUMBER` window function.

```
;WITH CTE_ACD AS (
  SELECT ResourceID, SessionID, TalkTime
  , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ResourceID ORDER BY TalkTime, SessionID) 
  FROM AgentConnectionDetail
  WHERE TalkTime > 0
) 
SELECT 
  R.ResourceID
, CONCAT(R.FirstName,' ',R.LastName) AS [Agent Name]
, A.SessionID
, A.TalkTime
FROM CTE_ACD A
JOIN Resource R ON R.ResourceID = A.ResourceID
WHERE A.RN <= 2;
```

Comment: Thx a lot LukStorms. your first query works for me. I should think about it in the other way around as you did but this didn't popup in my mind.